# Best method to organize buttons in JavaFX?

Tags: java, button, javafx, tableview

I am making some kind of visual menu with many buttons which are basically clickable icons opening new scene. What is best and easy (I am new to javafx) way to organize it? I was thinking about tableview but it seems bit hard in my situation. Can I use matrix in this situation?

Comment: Have a look at [`GridPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) and [`TilePane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) Both are covered in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Comment: Thanks, i already found it and using it in my program it's what i was looking for.